# Vaataakarshanashtra (वाताकर्षणास्त्र - a weapon which removes air or O2 from atmosphere)

Tags: weapon, war

Shree Navanathas are described to possess *Vaataakarshana Astra* (वाताकर्षणास्त्र - a weapon which removes air or O2 from atmosphere) in 'Shree Navanath Kathaasaar'.
But I didn't come across any reference of this astra in either Ramayana or Mahabharata.
Is there any reference of it in an era earlier to Navanathas?

Comment: I think this is one of the siddhis. This specific astra may or may not be mentioned but this type of siddhi might have some mention.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma In 'Shree Navanath Kathaasaar' which is in Marathi, it is clearly mentioned that each 'Naatha' tought this astra vidya to his disciples. There is further a story about Indra taking peacock's form and stealthily learning this astra while Matsyendranatha is teaching same astra to his disciple.